# Request failed when using Axios in ReactJs and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, axios, laravel-5.8

I using ReactJs as my front-end engine and I handle a request using Axios to get data from my Post table by Laravel I set route in `api.php` when I get a response and `console.log` it it shows Access to XMLHttpRequest at error at my chrome DevTool

api.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getIndex'
]);
```

my controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Posts;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){
        $post = Posts::all();

        return $post;
    }
}
```

my ReactJs file(App.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component{

    getData(){
        console.log(123);
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            }).catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <p>
                        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to amir.
                    </p>
                    { this.getData() }
                    <a
                        className="App-link"
                        href="https://reactjs.org"
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    >
                        Learn React
                    </a>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can try it. https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-cors-middleware-tutorialexample.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, First I create a Middleware using `php artisan make:middleware Cors` then the Cors class should be like this:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class Cors
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            return $next($request)
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-HEaders', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the laravel-cors package via composer

In your console: `composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors`

Then in your app/Http/Kernel.php add this to the middleware or specifically to api only
(for laravel-cors version 1.0 and above I believe)

```
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

or (0.11.3 in my other project)

```
\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```